# How do light switches with a small LED light indicator work?

Tags: switches

I found this type of [switch](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32814641240.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000013.7.73787dbbnvVXtB&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.13339.146401.0&scm_id=1007.13339.146401.0&scm-url=1007.13339.146401.0&pvid=db56ed6e-e278-4202-97bb-e39b3b340ca2&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller,scm-url:1007.13339.146401.0,pvid:db56ed6e-e278-4202-97bb-e39b3b340ca2,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%230_668%23808%234094%23786_668%23888%233325%2312_668%232846%238108%23137_668%232717%237564%23676_668%231000022185%231000066058%230_668%233468%2315614%23557) typically used for residential housing and though it will look good for my project. So basically its a glorified push-button.

I would like to use it with 5v along a 1meter cable for interfacing to my project. But i do not know if will work its rated 110v-220v so i do not know if 5v will work. Its only a contact inside so it should work, but it has a LED indicator inside so it must have some sort of circuit . These wall switches with led indicators are common on households but i could not find a schematic for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones with actual lamps in them typically use a neon indicator globes (not LEDs) that operate at mains voltage from a small current that is leaked through the lamp.  Although some may use a SPDT switch and switch the power to the indi
cator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYsDM0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So since there is still a physical contact switch present, my 5v circuit should still be able to work. I just wont be able to light the the lamps which is not that important anyway.

Comment: Yes switch will still work.

Answer (score 1):

The switch you linked to uses flourescence indicators, according to the description.
So it's not actively powered, but glows for some time after it was illuminated.

Comment: Oh, how about those with actual leds on them? i know some of them uses an actual LED